# Generic method to execute stored procedures and map result to a DTO class

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, ef-core-3.1

I'm starting a web application that is gonna work mostly with stored procedures(SPs).

I would like to highlight this question:
**Which is the best approach to execute SPs and map the result to a custom class (DTO)?
Is reflection a bad approach for mapping?**

I'm using EF core 3.1.3 database first, a DB with all my tables and SPs. I tried the next approach but I read that it's not good for the application performance due to I'm using *reflection* to map the DataReader to a class.

```
public List<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(string storedProcedure, List<SqlParameter> parameters) where T : new()
{
        using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // set some parameters of the stored procedure
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                parameter.Value = parameter.Value ?? DBNull.Value;
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }

            if (command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                command.Connection.Open();

            using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var entity = DataReaderMapToList<T>(dataReader);
                return entity;
            }
        }
}

private List<T> DataReaderMapToList<T>(DbDataReader dr)
{
            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasColumn(prop.Name) && !Equals(dr[prop.Name], DBNull.Value))
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(obj, dr[prop.Name], null);
                        }
                    }
                    list.Add(obj);
                }
                return list;
            }
            return new List<T>();
}
```

On the other hand, I'm using EF Core for the tables and simple queries.

I've been thinking of using EF to execute the SPs, but I couldn't find a good solution to make it generic and easy to map.

I'm open to different ideas. Thanks!

Comment: EF Core already allows this through the FromSqlRaw and FromSqlInterpolated methods

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I'm trying to make something generic using FromSqlRaw, tho maybe it's not necessary to make it more complex.

Comment: Why? It's *already* generic. You can pass parameters as an anonymous type, the same way you'd do with Dapper, or as an array of `SqlParameter` objects

Comment: The only way to get something more generic would be to use Dapper instead of EF, so you don't have to configure a `DbSet` even for keyless types. You could put that code in a method in your DbContext to avoid spreading data access code outside it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, I decided to use EF, anyway I have a doubt now. I thought that using Reflection was going to have a bad performance in the code I shared above, but I couldn't notice a big difference between EF and this code. Someone told me that reflection is not good at using it all time.

Answer (score 1):

Using EF, you will need classes for the results. Here is an example where I call a SProc to get some rows into a class called Visits. Note the array order of parameters matter here. If you want to specify a parameter by name then use @Sort=@Sort:

```
public virtual DbSet<Visits> SP_Visits { get; set; }

            SqlParameter[] parameters = {
                new SqlParameter("DateFrom", dateFrom),
                new SqlParameter("DateTo", dateTo),
                new SqlParameter("Aggregation", aggregation),
                new SqlParameter("Sort", sort)
                    };


    return await SP_Visits.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.sp_Visits @DateFrom, @DateTo, @Aggregation, @Sort", parameters).ToListAsync();
```

If you are happy to have coded classes, this is a simple, typesafe solution. If you want to have something that is absolutely dynamic then consider a DataTable. here is how it works in a simple case that you display a table of values from any SProc:

Call your SProc with the required parameters and, using a SqlDataReader, dump the contents into a DataTable.

Create a Shared partial view that takes a datatable as the model. Iterate the columns to get the number of table columns and in each one, set table header text. Iterate the rows and columns to display the values for each column for each row

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. 
That way would be a simple way to do it. I'm wondering if I really need to make it generic. 
Also, I have some situations where I need to return Output values, so I should define these parameters too.

Comment: In this example, you defined a DbSet, but in my situation, I have a DTO Keyless (no key) so I can't define it in this way. I had to add it in OnModelCreating as HasNokey()

Comment: That is interesting. My Sproc does interact with a simple-keyed table but the Sproc itself returns fields [aggregation name], [page name] and [visit count] - there is no defined key. The aggregation type is based on day/week/month/year so the Sproc SQL aggregates data using a case statement to count/group the rows. The aggregation column is a string that has the year/year-month/year-week/day depending on the aggregation selected